# Sorting, totaling and grouping by state

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, grouping

Very inexperienced MS Access 2013 user here. I have a large set of records I'm working with. The columns I'm working with are STATE and COMPANY NAME. There are hundreds of different company names and they change from week to week on my source excel file. They also duplicate themselves within each state, for instance: a certain company may have 15 records in one state and 2 in another

What I'd like to be able to produce is a simple click report in Access so I can sort by State. For example, the data I'm pulling into access is this:

[image]

This is just an example of TX. I'd like Access to produce a report that looks like this for each state or group of states:

[image]

As I said previously, the names of the companies will change week to week. They also will come and go. So one week ABC1 might not have any records and the next they could be back to 5. Any ideas on if this is possible with Access? I'd prefer not to sort with excel, I'd like to simply save the source file each week I get it and click on the report in Access. Thanks in advance for your time and energy, it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you to Rick Smith for getting the images in there.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at this post, it might help you.

http://www.fontstuff.com/access/acctut04.htm

Comment: Dave, thanks for the information. I've been trying to use that towards what I'm trying to accomplish, without much luck. Each record in the data I have is basically a data point, so for example: if company A shows up 20 times in the data with different addresses, company B shows up 15 times. I need those 20 records for Company A condensed into 1 with the number 20 in the next field. And so forth for Company B, C, D, etc...

Comment: This should give you what you want.

http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/numeric/count.php